# How to get data from Tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, dom, tags

I'm trying to reach some data in tag from another site. How to get data from inside of this tag?

My code:

```html
  <span id="duKaina">Kaina</span>
  <script>
    var url = 'http://www.eso.lt/lt/namams/elektra/tarifai-kainos-atsiskaitymas-ir-skolos/kiek-kainuoja-elektra-2017-m..html';
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
    var input = inputs[14];
    
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.responseType = 'document';
    
    request.onload = function sdas(){
      inputs.textContent = request.response;
    };
    
    request.send();
    document.getElementById('duKaina').innerHTML = input;
    console.log(input);
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to use `input.textContent` instead of `inputs.textContent`.

Comment: You're accessing `inputs.textContent` instead of the single one `input`. So you can't use `.textContent` on a list of nodes

Comment: but the console log is also undefined

Comment: `inputs[14]` does not exist - the response is `{
  "length": 0,
  "item": function item() { [native code] },
  "namedItem": function namedItem() { [native code] }
}`

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! But I see that I'm stuck with this situation. What I'm trying to do,  I'm selecting all H2 tags and want to get number from one of them, how i should to do that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The value you are trying to access ( `inputs[14]`) does not exist:

```html
  <span id="duKaina">Kaina</span><br>
  <span id="test">Kaina</span>
  <script>
    var url = 'http://www.eso.lt/lt/namams/elektra/tarifai-kainos-atsiskaitymas-ir-skolos/kiek-kainuoja-elektra-2017-m..html';
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
    var input = inputs[14];
    
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.responseType = 'document';
    
    request.onload = function sdas(){
      inputs.textContent = request.response;
    };
    
    request.send();
    document.getElementById('duKaina').innerHTML = input;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = inputs['length'];
    console.log(input);
    console.log(inputs);
    console.log(inputs[14]);
    console.log(inputs['length']);
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```